# unable to connect to git server via http: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

Tags: git, http, homebrew

For some time now I am not able to use git when remotes are set with a http url. I solved that problem by replacing the http url by corresponding ssh url. However, now I am stuck because I want to install homebrew and the install script attempts to call github through an http address. I get the following error:

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

Unfortunately, the internet didn't provide me a solution. The only thing I could find so far was something similar about a `git push` problem with suggested solutions to increase git's buffersize, change the http version to 1.1 or change the internet network. Neither of these options works for me.

Any ideas why I get that error or how to troubleshoot it? Thanks in advance

os: macOS monterey v12.1
tried it out with git versions v2.29.3, v2.32.0 and v2.34.1

Comment: For this kind of questions, it *really* helps to know the exact OS version you are running, as well as the exact Git version.

Comment: I am currently on macOS monterey version 12.1, but the problem appeared already on an older macOs version. I also tried it out with git v2.29.3, v2.32.0 and v2.34.1. In all cases I got the same error.

Comment: Are you using any sort of proxy, VPN, or TLS MITM device?  Any program whatever that might modify, intercept, or tamper with your network connections?

Comment: Not that I know of. I tried it with and without my work VPN, the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after much struggle I managed to solve my issue.

Running `git config --system -l` I could see that I had the following things set: http.extraheader, http.postbuffer, http.version, http.sslverify. I removed all of them with

`git config --global --unset ...` one by one

That solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case the closing VPN solved the problem.
Or change the internet connection.